# How to Implement CRON job in PHP to perform Delete action

Tags: php, jquery, timer, cron, sql-delete

I have a list of categories with delete button to individual row. When I click click `delete` I am updating one field in the database to track. The column name is "deleted". If I click `delete` it will update to `1` else `0`.

```
if ($_REQUEST['action'] == 'delete')
    {
        $Deleted = $conn->query("update r_category SET deleted = 1 where id_category = ".$id);
    }
}
```

I have written code to update that back to `0` if mistakenly deleted:

```
if ($_REQUEST['action'] == 'undo') {
    $UndoDelete = $conn->query("update r_category SET deleted = 0");
}
```

What I am looking for is when user does not 'undo', the deleted file has to
 be removed from database after 1 week. How can I approach that? Can anyone suggest me some code for this.

I have wrote this code and how can i call this

```
<?php
$Url      = "http://techdefeat.com/admin/category.php?action=undo"; 
$Handle   = curl_init($Url);
$Response = curl_exec($Handle);
curl_close($Handle);
?>
```

Comment: Your 'undo deletion' code un-deletes every item in your database

Comment: Apart from the fact that this does not even work as your sql is not valid (`$messageid` is an array...), the question is too broad.

Comment: i have updated question check it once. forget about array just tell how can i implement cron functionality

Comment: Amazing that this gets upvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to correct your `undo delete` code. Otherwise it's basically un-delete all the records in your table. Anyway, I'll share my suggestion for your question.

---

Since you were asking about a cron job, you can create an action in your web app to be called by a daily cron job at a specific time. As an example, following cron job will run at 1.00 AM everyday and call to the given URL.

> 0 1 * * * curl http://domain.name/endpoint/url

In this case, you will have to maintain 3 statuses for `deleted` field which,

- 0 - Not deleted
- 1 - Pending to delete
- 2 - Deleted

Initially, the `deleted` field will be set as 0. And if someone clicked on delete button, it can be updated as 1 which is "pending to delete". Also you need to change the table structure by adding a `deletedDate` field which will be set with the current timestamp when a `deleted` field updated as 1.

With the daily cron job running, within the action we can update all the "pending to delete" ( `deleted` = 1) records which are exceeding one week from the `deletedDate` to be marked as deleted by setting the `deleted` = 2 and `deletedDate` = "current timestamp".

This is just my opinion and normally, it's not recommended to using cron jobs for these kind of tasks since there are issues when it comes to scalability. The recommended way is implementing Task Queues and handle through them.